# Get Keys and Values from ArrayList - Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have an `ArrayList` that's defined as such.

```
{0=1, 1=com.myApp.entities.User@7ecfc3d9} // userList
```

`0` is the ID of the user, and 1 is a `User` HashMap. I'm trying to iterate over this list to populate a `select` with the user ID and user's name.

How can Thymeleaf display this with the following structure?

```
  <select th:field="*{user}">
    <option 
        th:each="user : ${userList}" 
        th:value="${user.getId}"  
        th:text="${user.getName}">
    </option>
  </select>
```

Comment: "I decided to do something else" isn't an acceptable answer. Questions must be answered as given.

Answer (score 0):

can you try the following code and let me know if this works for you

```
<select th:field="*{user}">
    <option 
        th:each="user : ${userList[1]}" 
        th:value="${user.getId}"  
        th:text="${user.getName}">
    </option>
  </select>
```